# Is there any way of checking if a website is using a 3rd party cookie?

Tags: cookies, automation

I have a list of websites that i have to check if there are any 3rd party cookies.

And going through everyone one of them an checking is not the smartest way of doing it..

Does any one know any solution of checking a hand full of links ?

If anyone has any idea let me know please.

I'm not sure if you need any more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking VSCode + Nunit + Selenium might be a pretty quick way to pop open a browser and confirm your cookies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit

pair that with some code like:

```
namespace YourProject
{
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

[TestFixture]
class Chrome
{

    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void StartTest()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void EndTest()
    {
        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckAllSiteCookies()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<YourFirstWebsite>"); 
        CookieCheck(cookieInfo);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<YourSecondWebsite>");
        CookieCheck(cookieInfo);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<YourThirdWebsite>");
        CookieCheck(cookieInfo);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<YourFourthWebsite>");
        CookieCheck(cookieInfo);
    }

    public void CookieCheck(string cookieInfo)
    {
     // C# example provided here for reading cookies
     // https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html
    }
}
}
```